# How to fix AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_config' in Bidirectional Layer

Tags: python, keras

Cannot solve this attribute error in bidirectional LSTM layer in Keras

I have tried replacing the bidirectional LSTM layer with fully connected and it works fine then.

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Bidirectional, Dense, Reshape, Lambda
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Add


img_w=197
img_h=197
channel=3
num_classes=8

input_layer = Input(name='the_input', shape=(img_w, img_h, channel), dtype='float32')
#(None, 197, 197, 3)
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, input_shape=(img_w, img_h, channel), weights='imagenet')(input_layer)
#(None, 7, 7, 2048)
base_model.trainable = False
r= Reshape(target_shape=((32, 3136 )), name='reshape')(base_model)
#(None, 32, 3136)
bi = Bidirectional(256,  merge_mode='concat')(r)
fc = Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='dense1')(bi)
```

Below is the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-27e3a3039ec6> in <module>()
     19 r= Reshape(target_shape=(100352, ), name='reshape')(base_model)
     20 #(None, 32, 3136)
---> 21 bi = Bidirectional(256,  merge_mode='concat')(r)
     22 inner = Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='dense1')(bi)
     23 #model = Sequential()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/wrappers.py in __init__(self, layer, merge_mode, weights, **kwargs)
    364                              '{"sum", "mul", "ave", "concat", None}')
    365         self.forward_layer = copy.copy(layer)
--> 366         config = layer.get_config()
    367         config['go_backwards'] = not config['go_backwards']
    368         self.backward_layer = layer.__class__.from_config(config)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_config'
```

Comment: The first argument for the `Bidirectional` constructor should be a `layer`. You are passing an integer (`256`).

Comment: You're passing the integer 256 into the layer parameter, I assume this is supposed to be a layer object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to read the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_config'
#^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- the kind of error: something doesn't have a needed attribute.
#                ^^^-- we had an integer...
#          ... when we needed something with a ^^^^^^^^^^ 'get_config'.

config = layer.get_config() # This is the line where the exception was thrown.
#        ^^^^^ This is what was supposed to have 'get_config', but didn't.
#        Since there are parentheses, it was a method call.
```

So, something named `layer` is supposed to have a `get_config` method, but at this point, it was an integer, and integers (unsurprisingly) don't have this method.

Where did `layer` come from? We keep working backwards:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/wrappers.py in __init__(self, layer, merge_mode, weights, **kwargs)
```

So, we were in the initialization of some sort of class, and `layer` is the first parameter that was passed. This also isn't within our own code but inside the library, so it's not something we can fix there. The conclusion is that something bad was passed as `layer`. We keep looking back:

```
bi = Bidirectional(256,  merge_mode='concat')(r)
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- the class we tried to instantiate
#                  ^^^--- the value passed for `layer`
```

Now we are in our code. Indeed, the value provided for `layer` is `256`, which is an integer. We tried to create an instance of the `Bidirectional` class, with something invalid. So the next step is to read the [documentation for that class](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/). We find that we need to have some sort of `Recurrent` layer here, for example an `LSTM` instance or a `GRU` instance. What you actually want will depend on the problem you're trying to solve; I don't know nearly enough about neural networks to help you any further. (But I'm *guessing* you want LSTM since you already `import`ed that and don't appear to be using it yet....)

Comment: A well-deserved upvote for teaching fishing, not just giving the fish.

Comment: Thanks Karl, I resolved the problem. I should have known better but got impatient and posted it.